# Loading NSMutableArray objects into an IBCollection of Labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

My problem is that when I use fast enumeration to load objects from my array, like so:

```
    for(SetOfObjects *set in _myArray){
    NSLog (@"%@"[set anObject];
    }
```

It will print out my specified object without a problem, however when it comes time to assign these objects to an NSArray of labels. The last object returns as 0.
Like so:

```
    for(SetOfObjects *set in _myArray){
     for(UILabel *label in _arrayOfLabels){
      int i = [set intObject];
       NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i];
       label.text = string;
      }
     }
```

I think, I have gone wrong here. The code works, but the problem is that all labels are then set as 0.

Any tips welcome.

Comment: you are setting to the all labels a value from last element of _myArray. aren't you?

Comment: Yes it seems so, thats what i thought was happening.

Comment: `int i = [set intObject];` what happen in this line?

Comment: This takes an integer object from _myArray and sets it to an int of i, If i where to print it out  with an NSLog it would appear with different numbers to that according to what was pulled out of the array in the first place. It would be in essence the same as the first enumeration I have put on here. 

        for(SetOfObjects *set in _myArray){
          NSLog (@"%i",[set intObject];
        }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are iterating the labels *within* each `SetOfObjects` instance, when in fact you want to iterate both arrays at the same time, which cannot be done using *fast enumeration*.

Instead revert to indexed-access of both arrays:

```
NSInteger count = [_myArray count];
NSAssert([_arrayOfLabels count] == count, @"Different array sizes!");
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < count; index++) {
    SetOfObjects *set = _myArray[index];
    UILabel *label = _arrayOfLabels[index];
    int i = [set intObject];
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i];
    label.text = string;
}
```

Note the assertion to check that both arrays are the same size.

**EDIT**: Oops, `i` was a bad variable name to choose for the index...

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, instantly worked as I coded it all in. I wouldn't have got that at all.